# SpriteKit memory leak in SKAction runblock

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am seeing a memory leak in the following code after I deinit the scene:

didMove of scene:

`run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.5), SKAction.run { [unowned self] in self.generateWave() }])))`

Function:

```
func generateWave()
{
    let bgImage = self.childNode(withName: "bgImage") as! SKSpriteNode

    let waveNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: atlasSplashScreen.textureNamed("SplashScreenWave"))

    waveNode.position = CGPoint(x: -207, y: -60.8)

    bgImage.addChild(waveNode)

    let waveMove = SKAction.moveTo(x: self.frame.width / 2, duration: 6)

    waveNode.run(waveMove)
    {
        waveNode.removeFromParent()
    }

}
```

Changing the last line to this fixes the leak:

`waveNode.run(SKAction.sequence([waveMove, SKAction.removeFromParent()]))`

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? I thought I was handling the weak/unowned stuff correctly, but now I am not sure. I don't get why putting the removeFromParent line in the completion block would cause a leak.

Thanks in advance.

Mike

Comment: You have a completion block at the end.  The completion block is retaining waveNode, while at the same time waveNode is retaining the completion block.  That is a retain cycle

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, thank you for the response. How would I break this cycle? I know normally you'd do [weak self] in, but since waveNode was declared inside the function, is it actually [weak waveNode] in? This doesn't seem right to me but I feel that I'm missing how to break the reference cycle otherwise. I apologize if this is very simple!

Comment: Make the local variable weak I believe so that it is not being retained by the function

Comment: Of course you are creating a new object, so you will need to create it with another variable, then clear the variable after you add it to bgimage

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify your last point? It seems that doing "[weak waveNode] in" fixes the leak - is there something else I should be doing? Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: You don’t want that because if your object is removed prior to the completion block it will crash. The idea is you do not want the function to retain the reference.  So you would create a temp strong reference variable, assign it, attach that object to the node, assign it to a weak reference, clear the string reference.  Now your object is only retained by the scene and the block, not the function.  When your completion fires, the scene will release, the block will release, all reference counts are now 0, your block will dealloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

waveNode is creating a strong reference to itself. You can unowned the reference, as it will only decrement its reference count by 1 (it is already 1 too high). In this particular case there doesn't seem to be a concern like Knight0fDragon is citing as this runBlock serves to remove your object itself; however, if it were set up a weak-strong dance, like:

```
[weak waveNode] in

guard let waveNode = waveNode else { return }
```

Apple discusses this at minute 31:00 of their WWDC on memory debugging from 2 years ago; it seems the community tends to focus on weak self issues as opposed to these "smaller leaks." Link to that video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/410/